# Referring to time of day in prose

Tags: numbers, time

> ```
> About ten after 10 PM, he answered the door again.
> ```

Someone said that having one number spelled and the other as digits was strange.  On the other hand, both digits doesn't seem right in a written-out sentence, either.  Is there a preferred way to write this?

Comment: "About ten past ten that night..."

Comment: I agree with tchrist that written-out numbers would be better in your example unless you were writing a police report, for instance.